# Concept of Hopfield Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

Just want to double check my understanding of comcept of Hopfield networks. would a trained hopfield network have an energy function that has local minimas equal to the number of the training patterns?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "training patterns"?

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes, but Hopfield net of a given size can have only so much local minima and if you try to train it with  larger number of training patterns then it fails and two patterns can become merged.